# Help in Numeircal evaluation of Carnot-Caratheodory norm given a signature.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-path-theory

The question is how to calculate Carnot—Caratheodory (CC) norm given a signature.
The equation is given in page 12 of the follwoing link:
http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~friz/master4_May6th.pdf

The |||g||| is defined in the second equation of page 12. (Do not know how to write the equation here)

Consider a signature say upto level 3;

level 1 is a vector L1= [1,2,3],

level 2 is 3 by 3 matrix M2= [1,2,3;4,5;6;7,8,9];

and level 3 is a 3 by 3 by 3

M3(:,:,1)=[1,2,3;4,5;6;7,8,9];

M3(:,:,2)=[11,12,13;14,15;16;17,18,19];and

M3(:,:,3)=[0.1,0.2,0.3;0.4,0.5;0.6;0.7,0.8,0.9];

The numbers are really arbitrary and is not representing any signature of particular path. The question is how to calculate the CC norm of this signature.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should warn that the cited pdf has 700 pages, most of them not relevant for your problem. You need to find out how norms for a tensor are defined. What is the underlying vector space norm? For instance, is $\||M_2|\|=\sup_{\|u\|=1,\|v\|=1}|u^TM_2v|$?

Comment: @LutzL, Thank you for your comments. I never mentioned it as I assumed that the calculation of the distance is not dependent on anything else but a specific procedure. Do you mean it would depend on the problem I am solving? One needs to discuss the problem first?

Comment: It would matter if you want to match a given result. Otherwise the finite-dimensional norms are equivalent, so the resulting topology is independent of the norm, which was the reason for introducing the CC norm to replace the geodetic distance in the first place.

Comment: @LutzL, I really did not understand the first sentences" "match a given result". May I ask what result are you referring? I understand we are postulating the paths so it would depend on the path. But what does "given result" mean?

Comment: If you are given an exercise where some fixed solution is expected, then you need to replicate all the ingredients of the original calculation that led to the reference solution. Else you just take $\|M_k\|=\sup_{\|u_1\|=...=\|u_k\|=1}\langle u_1⊗...⊗u_k,M_k\rangle$ as norm.